If set $F \subset X$ is closed in $X$ then every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in F$ for all $n$ converges to an element in $F$.

Let $X$ be a metric space. If set $F \subset X$ is closed in $X$ then every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in F$ for all $n$ converges to an element in $F$.

I have read proofs of the above. And they are mainly in the line:
Say $(x_n)$ converges to point $z$. Say $z\not\in F$ then $z\in X-F$.
How is it obvious that $z\in X-F$. Like $z$ might not be $\in F$ ( I know this is not true because $F$ is a metric space and closed itself, so any converging sequence in $X$ must converge to a point in $X$), however, I am not sure how to prove this.
Essentially, my question is,

if a sequence converges in a metric space, then it converges to a point in the metric space.


They are saying, suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is a convergent sequence, $(x_n)$, that converges to a point that is not in $X$. In particular, since each $x_n \in F \subset X$, we know that $(x_n)$, in being a convergent sequence, approaches a point in $X$. The exercise you are being asked to do is prove the stronger claim that it converges to a point in $F$.
So, you are seeing the setup for a proof by contradiction in which the supposition will be that $(x_n)$ converges to a point in $X$ but not $F$, i.e., to a point in $X - F$. From this, you will derive a contradiction, which will show that your supposition was incorrect and, therefore, the desired claim follows.

I think OP understands the proof by contradiction setup. They are more asking why "$(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence" tacitly implies that the point of convergence is in $X$.
